# Try/except to scrape sites with 3 random numbers in the end of URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape data from Brazil's Supreme Court using Python's BeautifulSoup and Requests.

Every one of the 144 links has a number between 1 and 3 in the end (e.g.: http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/remuneracao/listarRemuneracao.asp?periodo=012007&ano=2007&mes=01&folha=3).

There's no pattern in the 'folha'(sheet, in Portuguese) part. Some months are 1, others are 2 or 3. It seems random. When the URL with the wrong number is accessed, the site loads, but with the message 'A folha solicitada não é válida' (the requested sheet is invalid, in Portuguese).

In my code (below), after creating a list with the links without the 'sheet' number, I load the page and check if the message is there. If it is, with the try method, the code then attaches the following number (2 or 3) in the URL.

But the code doesn't run. Is there a way to use try/except for 3 possible outcomes in the code?

```
   records=[]
    for x in links:
        r = requests.get(x+'1')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        if BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') == 'A folha solicitada não é válida':
            try:
                r = requests.get(x+'2')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
                if BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') == 'A folha solicitada não é válida':
                    try:
                        r = requests.get(x+'3')
                        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
                    else:
                        continue
            else:
                continue

        mes = x[-30:-28]+'/'+x[-28:-24] 
        ativos = soup.find_all('table', {'id':'ministros_ativos'})
        ativos = ativos[0]
        for x in range(0,11):
            nome = ativos.find_all('a', {'class':'exibirServidor'})[x].text
        salarios = ativos.contents[3].findAll('td', {'align':'right'})
        salarios_brutos = salarios[::2]
        salarios_liquidos = salarios[1::2]
        for x in salarios_liquidos:
            liquido = x.text

        for x in salarios_brutos:
            bruto = x.text

        records.append((nome, bruto, liquido, mes))
```

Comment: What do you mean by the code doesn't run? Is there an error

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 Yes. In this configuration, there's a problem with the 'else' statement. But even if it ran, I'm interested to know if there is a more productive way to chose the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range` to create a list of numbers between 1 and 3, and iterate over that list to produce a url. If the response is valid break the loop and continue with your code.

```
for x in links:
    for i in range(1,4):
        try:
            r = requests.get(x+str(i))
        except Exception as e:
            continue
        if 'A folha solicitada não é válida' not in r.text:
            break
    else:
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Notes:

For python 2 you'll have to turn the error message to unicode. (use the `u` prefix)

`requests` won't raise an exception for a 404 response so you don't need a try/except for that, however other exceptions may occur.

Use `except` to catch exceptions. `else` is used after `except` in a try/except/else block, and is executed if no exceptions occur.

The `else` statement in the for/else block is executed if the loop doesn't break. Basically it means "continue with the next `x` if no valid response is recieved".